# MySQL INSERT INTO Mytable VALUES(NULL) WHERE VALUES ('NA');

Tags: mysql

I have in Mytable some value = 'NA' 
Insted of this value I would like to put NULL. 
So I've write:

```
INSERT INTO Mytable
VALUES(NULL)
WHERE VALUES('NA');
```

But I didn't work.
I didn't put the name of the column because potentially all column can have some 'NA' value. 
I hope someone have a idea to do it. 
Regards
Sam

Comment: A `WHERE` clause makes no sense in context of an `INSERT`, as for inserts, the row doesn't exist yet and therefore would not pass ANY filtering cirteria.  It looks like you are wanting an `UPDATE` query.

Comment: I've try as well with : UPDATE Mytable SET VALUE = NULL WHERE VALUES(NA) ; and I have error code 1054 unknown column 'NA'

Comment: Have you looked at MySQL documentation at all for proper syntax??

Comment: If you are trying to change all NULL values in a table to `NA` (and I am not sure what you think you are gaining from this). Then you might simply want to modify you table columns to have default value of 'NA' and be set to `NOT NULL`.  This would force your table to update all these values to `NA` without running a specific UPDATE query. This is also future proof, as you would get 'NA' values for these columns when no value is specified on insert.  Of course, this is actually very unconventional behavior. Typically you would replace NULL value with 'NA' only for display purposes.

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE Mytable
SET value = NULL
WHERE value = 'NA';
```

Yes, you must do this for each column/attribute that you want to update.

Comment: I've try it but it give me : error 1054 unknown column value

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Mytable SET value = NULL WHERE value = 'NA'
```

Comment: I've try it but it give me : error 1054 unknown column value

Comment: When I say `value`, it's implied that you need to replace `value` with the actual name of your column. To be honest, I think you need to learn more about the basics of SQL. This link could be a good start, although there are probably better resources out there: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp

Comment: Thanks for the link. The thing is that I don't know which column contain some NA so I want to select all of them and test if in some there are some NA. select * select all the column but we can't use it here.

Answer (score 1):

To replace occurrences of `'NA'` with `NULL` in multiple columns, for all rows in a table, you can do this in a single update query. The trick is to assign the current value of the column back to the column when you don't want the value changed.

For example:

```
UPDATE Mytable t
   SET t.column_one = IF(t.column_one='NA',NULL,t.column_one)
     , t.column_two = IF(t.column_two='NA',NULL,t.column_two)
     , t.column_fee = IF(t.column_fee='NA',NULL,t.column_fee)
 WHERE t.column_one = 'NA'
    OR t.column_two = 'NA'
    OR t.column_fee = 'NA'
```

NOTES:

Repeat the column assignment for each column you need to do the replacement. (The example above references three columns, named `column_one`, `column_two` and `column_fee`. I don't know the names of the columns in your table; you would need to replace those references with the actual names of the columns in your table.)

The `WHERE` clause is optional; the query would have the same net result without that WHERE clause. (Without the `WHERE` clause, the query would update every row in the table; any rows that don't have an 'NA' in one of the three columns would not be changed, since the columns will all be assigned their current values.

For a lot of columns, it's more efficient to do it in a single operation, to apply several changes to a row in one statement, rather than separate statements each making updates to the same row.)

The expresssion `IF(a,b,c)` evaluates expression `a` as a boolean; if it returns TRUE, it returns expression `b`, otherwise it returns expression `c`.

---

To see how this works, you can run a SELECT statement (remove the SET clause, and replace the `UPDATE` keyword with SELECT and relevant expressions in the SELECT list:
For example:

```
SELECT t.column_one                            AS _one_old
     , IF(t.column_one='NA',NULL,t.column_one) AS _one_new
     , t.column_two                            AS _two_old
     , IF(t.column_two='NA',NULL,t.column_two) AS _two_new
     , t.column_fee                            AS _fee_old
     , IF(t.column_fee='NA',NULL,t.column_fee) AS _fee_new
  FROM Mytable t
 WHERE t.column_one = 'NA'
    OR t.column_two = 'NA'
    OR t.column_fee = 'NA'
```

The `_old` columns return the existing values in the columns; the `_new` columns return the value that would be assigned (by the UPDATE statement earlier in my answer.)

The results from that query will verify that `IF()` expressions will return a NULL when the existing value in the column is `'NA'`; it will also confirm that the `IF()` expression will return the existing value when the existing value in the column is not `'NA'`.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

With 20 different tables with 12 columns each, I'd make use of the `information_schema.columns` table in MySQL to help me generate the required expressions.

Something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('    , t.'
        ,c.column_name,' = IF(t.'
        ,c.column_name,'=''NA'',NULL,t.'
        ,c.column_name,')') AS expr
  FROM information_schema.columns c
 WHERE c.table_schema = 'mydatabase'      -- the name of your database
   AND c.table_name   = 'mytable'         -- the name of your table
   AND c.data_type IN ('varchar','char')  -- only character type columns
 ORDER BY c.ordinal_position
```

Which will return something like this:

```
expr
-------------------------------------
    , t.fee = IF(t.fee='NA',NULL,t.fee)
    , t.fi = IF(t.fi='NA',NULL,t.fi)
    , t.fo = IF(t.fo='NA',NULL,t.fo)
    , t.fum = IF(t.fum='NA',NULL,t.fum)
```

So, this doesn't actually update the table, it's just a convenient way to avoid typing out a bunch of SQL expressions. You can copy that result set, and use it to form a statement similar to the one I showed in my answer above.  (Obviously, you would omit rows that you don't want to change, and the first comma would need to be changed to the `SET` keyword, and the rest of the statement would need to be wrapped around this.

Personally, I wouldn't bother with a WHERE clause, because if it's a lot of columns, the query is going to do a full scan of the table anyway.

```
SELECT CONCAT(' OR t.',c.column_name,' = ''NA''') AS expr
  FROM information_schema.columns c
 WHERE c.table_schema = 'mydatabase'      -- the name of your database
   AND c.table_name   = 'mytable'         -- the name of your table
   AND c.data_type IN ('varchar','char')  -- only character type columns
 ORDER BY c.ordinal_position
```

This will return something like:

```
expr
----------------------
 OR t.fee = 'NA'
 OR t.fi = 'NA'
 OR t.fo = 'NA'
 OR t.fum = 'NA'
```

**CAUTION:** be careful that you don't do comparison of numeric columns to `'NA'`, because MySQL will evaluate `'NA'` as a numeric value of zero (`0`) in a numeric context.

Comment: Yes but none of my column are totaly full of NA, only some value are NA in some column

Comment: The UPDATE statement in my answer will only affect rows that have an 'NA' in one of those three columns. It doesn't change any rows that don't have an `'NA'`, and it doesn't replace any existing values other than `'NA'`. The "trick" is to assign the current value of the column back to the column. Only values of 'NA' will get replaced.

Comment: I think it s the best way to do it. I just wanted to avoid to write the select column by column because I have 20 tables and 12 column in each tables. And of course all the column's names are different.

Comment: @user3542259: SQL requires that the columns to be accessed and modified be specified, just like the table has to be specified. MySQL does have table metadata conveniently available the information_schema database; i make frequent use of this to help me generate SQL.